Can pure colors be reflected from a non-light source object?
I wanted to print something in pure cyan and I learned that I can actually not achieve the exact color I was looking for (#00FFFF in RGB for context). I now have this question about these "pure" colors. Using RGB for reference can the colors that arise from combining 100% red, blue and green be reflected by a physical object in the real world? By combining I mean the colors: cyan (#00FFFF), yellow (#FFFF00) and magenta (#FF00FF). These are the result of combining 100% green and blue, 100% red and green and 100% red and blue, respectively. These can be seen exactly on a phone screen because it consists of tiny lights, but cam the same happen for an object that does not emit light but reflects it?

This question doesn't seem to be about the physics of light, but rather about human perception of color, about representation of color in software, and about the availability of particular pigments from one or more printing companies.

@rob What I mean is, if there is a specific way we can paint, a table for example, so that when light from a light source falls to it, we interpret it as pure, let's say magenta. I just used the RGB codes for reference to denote the exact colors that arise from the mix variations from 2 of the 3 primary electromagnetic color wave lengths (being red, green and blue).
